# Google Maps callback url

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, callback, nsurl

I have the following code:

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://")!) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://
    saddr=28.458125,77.033833&daddr=18.407000,73.506300&directionsmode=driving
    &x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=Back+to+my+app")!)

}
```

My app opens Google Maps app, but doesn't show the back to my app button. I read things about a callback URL implementation in AppDelegate.swift, but I couldn't find how to do this. I guess it has something to do with the x-success parameter

Can someone help me please?

Comment: This behavior should be implemented by default on a device running iOS 9.x

Comment: Hmm, it is not the way it works now. Can you find an error in my code?

Comment: I'm saying I don't think you should need the code. If your situation is one where your user opens a link to google maps app from inside your app, if they are running iOS 9.x, then the system will implement this button natively. If it's something else then this may not apply.

Comment: You mean the '< back to App' text at the top left? I am aware of this, but I was wondering if this callback method could be applied, because I want to be sure my user returns to my app.